# Mysql no day repeat

Tags: mysql, date, distinct, repeat

In my database I have a table with: day of week, date and events.
One date can contain **one** or **more** events.

**The query:**

```
SELECT *  ,
DATE_FORMAT(fromDate, '%d-%m-%Y') as date_eu,
DATE_FORMAT(fromDate, '%d') as date,
DAYNAME(fromDate) as weekday 
FROM `calendar` WHERE YEAR(fromDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND 
      MONTH(fromDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
      ORDER BY date ASC
```

**So I get in the table:**

```
Tuesday     01  event1

Tuesday     01  event2

Wednesday   02  event1

Wednesday   02  event2
```

**This is what I want:**

```
Tuesday     01  event1

                event2

Wednesday   02  event1

                event2
```

(No repeat from a date and weekday in the list, if it contains more than ONE event)

Someone an idea? Maybe  DISTINCT, but can't find a right solution.

[image]

Comment: can you make this blob of text a proper question please ?

Comment: Sorry , bad English.. this is a query to become date and events for a calendar , if more than one  event in a  day , i wil no repeat  from the date and weekday only the event.